# Batch zipping multiple folders content

Tags: command-line, bash, 7-zip

If I want to 7z or winrar multiple folders content only. How or what would be the best method?
Example:
D:\PS1 PSX PLAYSTATION USA REDUMP EVERY GAME 1 OF 4[!!!!!!.COM]_Action Man - Operation Extreme (USA)\Action Man - Operation Extreme (USA).bin
D:\PS1 PSX PLAYSTATION USA REDUMP EVERY GAME 1 OF 4[!!!!!!.COM]_Action Man - Operation Extreme (USA)\Action Man - Operation Extreme (USA).cue
and I just want Action Man - Operation Extreme (USA).7z (contains bin and cue).
Is there a batch option to complete multi folders?
Chris

Comment: The answer to your question  is: Just specify the desired folder names.  e.g.: " 7z a -tzip -mx=9 -mfb=258 -mpass=15 filename.zip dir1 dir2 " (without the quotes I show).  You may need to use escaping for files with spaces (or dashes?); easiest way is to throw quotation marks around the filename.  Windows has different paths/executable names, different from Unix.  Your references to "D:\" implies Windows (or DOS, but Windows seems more probable), yet your "bash" tag implies Unix.  Well, there is a "bash" for Windows, but I'm guessing that isn't want you were really trying to do.Please clarify.

Comment: These actions would be in a Windows environment.I want to zip the contents only of 300 folders, without the folders being included and each folders content be a separate zip file. Is that possible to do in a batch? Each folder contains a .bin and .cue file.  So the above file complete should be Action Man - Operation Extreme (USA).zip and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> for /d %X in * do echo "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -mx=9 -mpass=15 -mfb=258 %X.zip %X

If that is successfully showing the folders you like, do it again, but take out the word "echo".

This answer is assuming a rather recent version of Microsoft Windows (Windows 7 ought to be okay, and I think Windows XP as well), with command extensions enabled (which is default behavior).  (Other solutions may exist for other platforms.)